# What is "The parameterized query ... which was not supplied." error?

Tags: c#, httphandler

I have experienced an error on

```
"The parametrized query '(@blue nvarchar(4000))SELECT blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBal' expects the parameter '@blue',
which was not supplied."
```

I am doing a HttpHandler.

I want to retrieve the image from the database. My codes are as below.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string image = context.Request.QueryString["image"];

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyCloudGames;Integrated Security=True"); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBall WHERE objective = blue", con); 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("blue", image); 

    con.Open(); 
    byte[] ballImage = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
    con.Close(); 

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; 
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(ballImage, 78, ballImage.Length - 78); 
}
```

The error occurred at

```
byte[] ballImage = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) instead of [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) method.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBall WHERE objective = @blue", con); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blue", image);
```

You should provide your parameter with `@` in your command.

> Soner Gönül, image is null. How can I correct it?

So, you should return `DBNull.Value` if your `image` is `null`. You can't pass a `null` on a required parameter. You can use a method as an alternative like;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT blueBallImage FROM CorrespondingBall WHERE objective = @blue", con); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blue", CheckForDbNull(image));

...

public static object CheckForDbNull(object value)
{
   if(value == null)
   {
       return DBNull.Value;
   }

   return value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! However, it is not working. The same error still occured.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui Check my updated question. Remember to use `@blue` instead of `blue`.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui Are you sure your `image` is not null? Check with debugger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38311/discussion-between-liu-jia-hui-and-soner-gonul)

Comment: Okay. I have tried your newest solution, but it isn't working. The same error occurred.